# Powershell DeElevate user token

Tags: authentication, powershell, uac

I have a situation which I think isn't necessarily odd in an Enterprise environment...

We're migrating to Windows 7, and due to the whole split token madness that is UAC, our vbscript network drive script has broken. There's a decent explanation at http://pcloadletter.co.uk/2010/05/15/missing-network-drives/ with a vbscript solution that creates a scheduled task each time someone logs in in order to run the drive mapping script in a non-elevated context.

This seems kludgey to me. What I'd rather do is deelevate the logon script so that it runs under the standard user token, rather than the elevated token. The problem is, I'm not sure how to go about that, and hoping someone here might be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer (doesn't provide you a way to de-elevate the token) but this may be solution you need to have drives show up:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/92db05ba-ff0d-4e73-b40a-78522bfab6aa

To configure the EnableLinkedConnections registry value, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press Enter.
2. Locate and then right-click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
3. Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
4. Type EnableLinkedConnections, and then press Enter.
5. Right-click EnableLinkedConnections, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Comment: The problem with EnableLinkedConnections is that it lowers the security of the Operating System and increases the attack surface - admittedly not by a lot. Though the link was useful, I hadn't stumbled across that link yet. In that discussion one of the participants mentioned that this is no longer an issue in Windows 7, and furthermore, that the issue of drives not being mapped only affects administrative users - which is not what's happening to me. No users are getting their drives mapped when script runs as part of the GPO, but you will get drives if you run the script manually.

Comment: @JohnBruckler So your logon script runs as admin? From the discussion it looked like a logon script can run in the security context of the logged on user.

Comment: I'm going to have to do more research on this. We have an offline version of the same script, and when running it, I get a UAC prompt a couple of times, but when it's running as a logon script I get no prompt. My normal login ID is a standard user, a member of only the local Users group.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question of deelevating via PowerShell, it does seem to be the 'best' answer in regards to getting drive mapping working (via login scripts at least). So, marking as answer.